# How to pad a string with 'X' to a minimum length in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Recently, in my GCSE computer science class we were told to code a program that would take someone's first name and surname in one string and then take the first letter of the first name and the first four letters of the surname and print it out, however, if the user did not have a surname longer than one character it would replace the blank spaces with the letter 'X'.

In exams we're not allowed access to the internet so I developed this program without using the internet, but now I was wondering if there was an easier way of coding the program that I made.

```
while True:
    fullname = input("\nPlease type in your firstname and your surname: ")

    space = fullname.index(" ")
    length = len(fullname)
    x = "X"

    endsur = length - 1
    initialfirst = fullname[0]

    fullsurname = endsur - space

    if fullsurname >= 4:
        startsur = space + 1
        secondsur = space + 2
        thirdsur = space + 3
        fourthsur = space+ 4

        surname = fullname[startsur] + fullname[secondsur] + fullname[thirdsur] + fullname[fourthsur]

        print(initialfirst,surname)

        again = input("\nWould you like to go again? (Y/N)")

        if again == "y":
            continue
        if again == "n":
            print("Goodbye!")
            quit()

    if fullsurname == 3:
        startsur = space + 1
        secondsur = space + 2
        thirdsur = space + 3

        surname = fullname[startsur] + fullname[secondsur] + fullname[thirdsur] + x

        print(initialfirst,surname)

        again = input("\nWould you like to go again? (Y/N)")

        if again == "y":
            continue
        if again == "n":
            print("Goodbye!")
            quit()

    if fullsurname == 2:
        startsur = space + 1
        secondsur = space + 2

        surname = fullname[startsur] + fullname[secondsur] + x + x

        if again == "y":
            continue
        if again == "n":
            print("Goodbye!")
            quit()

    if fullsurname == 1:
        startsur = space + 1

        surname = fullname[startsur] + x + x + x

        if again == "y":
            continue
        if again == "n":
            print("Goodbye!")
            quit()

    if fullsurname <= 0:
        print("\nIt looks like you've not put in your surname. Please make sure to use a space between your firstname and your surname.")
```

Comment: Yes, could be way shorter, you should post it in CodeReview instead since it's a working code

Comment: Fixed the indentation. It looks like you didn't highlight `while true` when you tried to format it as code.

Comment: And if the code above is complete, and working, it's not typically considered ontopic here. Code Review is for improving working code.

Comment: Code doesn't seem to work. 
`Please type in your firstname and your surname: ayta ada
a adaX` According to your desc, the X is only supposed to be there if surname is <=1 char.

Comment: Wasn't aware of code review at the time, thank you for the information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while True:
    name = input('What is your name? ')
    name = name.split(' ')
    first_name = name[0]
    last_name = name[1]

    if len(last_name) < 4:
        last_name += 'x'*(4-len(last_name))

    together = first_name[0] + last_name[0:4]

    #You can add your error checks here
    print(together)

    cont = input('Would you like to go again? ')
    if cont == 'y':
        pass
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is an addon to  @Wright 's answer: tip: avoid making unnecessary variables to further condense code and avoid namespace flooding

```
while 1:
    first_name, last_name  = input('What is your name? ').split(' ')
    if len(last_name) < 4:
        last_name += 'x'*(4-len(last_name))   
    together = first_name[0] + last_name[0:4]
    print(together)
    if input('Would you like to go again? ') != 'y':
        break
```

Comment: Indeed, however I wrote my code the way I did so its reasonably short while also self explanatory. Once he understands it he can minimize it on his own to what you've just shown.

Comment: Yup as I said mine was only an add on to yours

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Enter your firstname and your surname (ex. Christopher Brown)")

while True:
    name = input('> ').split()
    if name == ['q']:
        exit()
    elif len(name) < 2:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue

    print(name[0][0],name[1][:4 if len(name[1]) >= 4 else len(name[1])]+'X'*(4-len(name[1])))
```

I siginificantly shortened your code for you, I moved all of the input getting for the names to one variable on one line and then it does some checking and prints it all from one line, you're welcome!!!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to ensure that the surname has enough characters is to append the `'XXXX'` padding first.

```
fullname = input(…)
firstname, surname_x = (fullname + "XXXX").split()
print(firstname[0], surname_x[:4])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Python's [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align) for this.

```
while True:
    name = input('What is your name? ')
    print('{:.1}{:x<4.4}'.format(*name.split(' ', 1)))
    if input('Would you like to go again? ') != 'y':
        break
```

`.1` and `.4` indicate that the first and second names are to be truncated, while `x<4` indicates the second name should be padded with `x`s.